# Как преобразовать запись МФА в транскрипцию на русском языке?

Tags: python, c#, мфа

Товарищи, приветствую! Ищу информацию (или утилиту или кусок кода) преобразования записи в формате международного фонетического алфавита (IPA) перевести в русскую транскрипцию.

Пример: дано слово `maɾɛ` - надо получить `марэ`. Таблицу "МФА-русский" уже [нагуглил](https://easypronunciation.com/ru/russian-letters-pronunciation-ipa-chart), однако она не покрывает случаи, когда символ МФА отсутствует в русской фонетике (типа гортанного французского р). А также ещё один пример, даже не знаю как описать: если слово начинается с `iẽ`, побуквенная транскрипция даст `иэ`, хотя более правильно будет `йе` (то есть задача преобразования контекстно-зависимая, простым набором замен не обойдёшься).

ЗЫ. Метки (не могу создать сам): МФА, транскрипция, фонетика.

Язык кода не особо важен, но предпочтительно Python или C# =) Также если подскажете статью, в которой описаны правила подобной трансляции, я также буду благодарен.

Comment: Создал метку, пригодится кому-нибудь.

Comment: Ну так это, МФА для того и создан, чтобы передавать любые звуки любых языков. Обратное, по сути, невозможно.

Comment: @alexander-petrov когда требуется со 100% точностью, то вы, разумеется, правы. Но я про задачу, где достаточно фонетики уровня "лэт ми спик фром зэ боттом ов май харт".

Comment: @aepot За метку огромное спасибо!

Comment: Как мне кажестся, хоть вопрос и про разработку, но он всё же больше про лингвистику, чем про программирование. Попробуйте сначала с точки зрения матчасти подъехать. https://rus.stackexchange.com/ задайте вопрос экспертам по языкам.